# making JSON string manually in php which is breaking line on urls

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create json manually using string in php by parsing an xml file. I created the whole json but when i am validating it; i can see unnecessary line breaks in between which causes the validation to fail.
This is part of my json.

```
"basicInfo": {
            "title": "Mini Figures Heroes Assemble Building Toys Taskmaster Martain Storm Thor #v6lo01",
            "viewItemURL": "http
://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-Figures-Heroes-Assemble-Building-Toys-Taskmaster-Martain-Storm-Thor-v6lo01-
/351370851384?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0",
            "galleryURL": "http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/myYu_MI3-mPtA6s3bJboaVA
/140.jpg",
            "pictureURLSuperSize": "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/OTAwWDEzNTI=/z/lQEAAOSwqu9VJ-Fy/$_3.JPG",
            "convertedCurrentPrice": "7.76",
            "shippingServiceCost": "0.0",
            "conditionDisplayName": "New",
            "listingType": "Auction",
            "location": "China",
            "categoryName": "Comic Book Heroes",
            "topRatedLising": "false"
        },
```

As you can see that the line is breaking for url.

In the php code i am just concatenating directly.

```
$resultxml.='"viewItemURL":"'.$grandchild->viewItemURL;
                             $resultxml.='",';
                             $resultxml.='"galleryURL":"'.$grandchild->galleryURL.'",';
```

I have no idea what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Don't try to create JSON manually. Create an array containing the structure you want, and then use `json_encode()`.

Comment: The line breaks must be coming from the XML file. Your code doesn't add any line breaks, so it must be in `$grandchild->viewItemURL`.

Comment: `json_encode` will correctly translate the newlines to `\n` in the JSON, which your code doesn't do (that's why you shouldn't try to do it by hand). If the newlines shouldn't be there at all, you need to resolve that separately.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode. An example:

```
<?php

/*
  If $grandchild->viewItemURL = "http
  ://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-Figures-Heroes-Assemble-Building-Toys-Taskmaster-Martain-Storm-Thor-v6lo01-/351370851384?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0"
 Value whith carriage return
*/

$data = array(
    "basicInfo" => array(
        "title" => $grandchild->title,
        "viewItemURL" => str_replace( "\n", '', $grandchild->viewItemURL ),
        "galleryURL" => str_replace( "\n", '', $grandchild->galleryURL ),
        "pictureURLSuperSize" => str_replace( "\n", '', $grandchild->pictureURLSuperSize ),
        "convertedCurrentPrice" => $grandchild->convertedCurrentPrice,
        // .
        // . and more items
        // . 
                        )
              );

$dataJson = json_encode( $data );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments, that you shouldn't create it manually.

**However, to answer your question...**

I copied your JSON and looked at it, and all the URLs have a space between : and // in the http://.

> "viewItemURL": "http: //www.ebay.com/itm/Mini[...]",
>
> "galleryURL": "http: //thumbs1.ebaystatic.com[...]",

As you can see, you also have a space after each colon ":", i.e. between the colon and the JSON value.
I guess you have another function (not posted here), which adds the space after each colon and it does that for URL as well.